# Unity lost and login loop after installing AMD Omega 15.5 drivers

Tags: ati, 14.10

I downloaded the three Deb files for the driver, control panel and open gl and cl files and installed them with the command line dpkg install command each of the three files. Now, first off I got a login loop but I fixed it by purging and installing fglrx and I'm able to log in but if I install the three 15.5 Deb files then back into a login loop. Another thing is, my unity panels are gone if I am able to log in, is there a possibility to install AMD Omega 15.5 drivers at this point and get my desktop back?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | egrep 'VGA|Display' -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

You can return your unity panels by installing CCM and turning on Unity.
Run in terminal

```
 sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
 ccsm
```

Then check Unity checkbox.